# Android Java Refresh / Reload App Fragment

Tags: java, android, date, fragment, refresh

How is it possible in Android Java to refresh / reload the fragment page / pages.

I have 4 Fragment pages, with a date counter, which shows the month,weeks,days,minutes to a specific date.

The problem is that it does not update if the application is open.

lets say it says 1 day 2 weeks 10 minutes to a date, when I let the app open for 2 minutes the minute counter won't change.

Piece of code:

```
// date format
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
// current date time
String now = format.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
// specific date
String date01 = "22/12/2015 21:10:00";

Date d1 = null;
Date d2 = null;

    try {
        d1 = format.parse(now);
        d2 = format.parse(date01);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    long diff = d2.getTime() - d1.getTime();

if (diffDays >= 0 && diffHours >= 0 && diffMinutes > 0) {
            ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.rest_time)).setText(diffDays + days
                    + diffHours + hours + diffMinutes + minutes);
```

so calculation works.

Comment: What do you do with these variables before this conditional??

Comment: They just tell the difference in days hours and minutes from the current time right now to a specific date, I will edit wait a second

Answer (score 0):

Consider using d2.compareTo(d1) instead or simpler .after() and .before()

Comment: I do not understand what you mean excatly sorry